# event.timeStamp to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

```js
$('#submit').on('click',function(e){
 var $textVal = $('#textVal').val();
 var $listItems = $('.listItems'); 
 var timeAdded = e.timeStamp;

 $listItems.prepend('<li>' + $textVal + ' added at ' + timeAdded  + '</li>');


 $('#textVal').val(' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <ol class="listItems">
  
 </ol>
</div>
<input type="textarea" placeholder="What to do?" id="textVal">
<input type="submit" value="To do!" id="submit">
```

When a toDo list item is added by pressing the to do! button, to add the item and the date that was added. I tried using the `e.timeStamp` but its showing the number of milliseconds from january 1st 1970 to when the event was triggered. I tried to convert that but I fail . How should I convert it so I get the exact time and date that the list item was added?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using 'new Date()' instead of 'e.timeStamp'?

Comment: no i didnt i wasnt sure , which is the most accurate way to achieve that . I thought that e.timeStamp its gonna be the most accurate one

Comment: Timestamp gives you a period as you can see in this [link](http://api.jquery.com/event.timestamp/). If i were you i would try to use the  Date method of jQuery like this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/)

Comment: thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.timeStamp` is supposed to equal `new Date().getTime()`. It's currently not. My advice would be to ignore the event timeStamp and use a common Date object.

```js
$('#submit').on('click',function(e){
 var $textVal = $('#textVal').val();
 var $listItems = $('.listItems'); 
    var dateAdded = new Date();

 $listItems.prepend('<li>' + $textVal + ' added at ' + dateAdded  + '</li>');


 $('#textVal').val(' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <ol class="listItems">
  
 </ol>
</div>
<input type="textarea" placeholder="What to do?" id="textVal">
<input type="submit" value="To do!" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

use javascript date object

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  var $textVal = $('#textVal').val();
  var $listItems = $('.listItems');
  var timeAdded = new Date;

  $listItems.prepend('<li>' + $textVal + ' added at ' + (timeAdded.getDay() + '-'+ (timeAdded.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + timeAdded.getFullYear() + " " + timeAdded.getHours() + ":" + timeAdded.getMinutes() ) + '</li>');

  $('#textVal').val(' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ol class="listItems"></ol>
</div>
<input type="textarea" placeholder="What to do?" id="textVal">
<input type="submit" value="To do!" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the moment library and

```
var date = moment(timeAdded)
```